# Disable core file generation in RHEL7

Tags: rhel, core-dump, sysctl

I'm currently running RHEL7.  I haven't been able to find a definitive explanation of how to disable core dump files.  I can limit to number of core files that are produced, but I don't know how to disable them entirely.  I limited the number of core files that get generated by adding

```
   kernel.core_uses_pid = 0
   kernel.core_pattern = core
```

to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

and running `sudo sysctl -p`

This limits core file generation to a single file that gets rewritten each time there's a core dump.  But I'd like to stop this file from being generated altogether.  Thanks!

EDIT:  I also tried this:

Add the line `Storage:none` to

`/etc/systemd/coredump.conf`

This didn't change anything, core files still get produced.

Comment: This may be related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182820/how-to-disable-core-dump-generation-in-centos-cpanel-server

Comment: check /lib/systemd/system/kdump.service. You can use systemctl stop kdump and systemctl disable kdump.Actually you need to turning linux kernel. Maybe you ran application that needed turning kernel.

Comment: **"Actually you need to turning linux kernel. Maybe you ran application that needed turning kernel. "**

Thank you for your help.  Could you please clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

I think core dump generation is related to ABRT. Can you check if the following services are running ?

## systemctl status abrtd

## systemctl status abrt-ccpp

And if they are, stop and disable them ( systemctl stop / disable  )

Comment: Neither of those services are present on my system

Comment: Have you tried this ?https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-disable-core-dumps/

Comment: Yes, it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

According to STIGs (RHEL 7 V-72057), this is covered by `dump.service`. You can check whether that is active with the following:

```
Verify that kernel core dumps are disabled unless needed.

Check the status of the "kdump" service with the following command:

# systemctl status kdump.service kdump.service
- Crash recovery kernel arming Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kdump.service; enabled)
- Active: active (exited) since Wed 2015-08-26 13:08:09 EDT; 43min ago
- Main PID: 1130 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) kernel arming.
```

If kernel core dumps are not required, disable the "kdump" service with the following command:

```
systemctl disable kdump.service
```